# Space curve defined by it's normal vector field

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let $N: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a vector field such that $||N(s)|| =1$ for all $s\in (a,b)$. Prove that there is unique (up to isometry) curve $\alpha: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $N$ is the normal vector field of the curve $\alpha$.

My idea is to express tangent and binormal vector fields in terms of $N$ and then I can easily calculate curvature and torsion. Finally you can use fundamental theorem of curves to get the result. My problem is how to get $T$ in terms of $N$?

**Edit**

There is a counterexample for any planar curve. Can we prove the theorem assuming that the torsion is not zero, i.e. the curve is not planar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the statement is wrong. Let us consider the biregular curve which describes a circle, $\alpha(s) = (\cos(s), \sin(s),0)$ and the biregular curve which describes a helix, $\beta(s)= (\sqrt{2}^{-1}\cos(s),\sqrt{2}^{-1}\sin(s),\sqrt{2}^{-1}s)$.

The normal vector for a biregular curve is given by the normalized vector of $x''(s)$, which in both cases is:$$N(s) = (-\cos(s),-\sin(s),0).$$

In this case, the two curves are not isometric as they have torsion $0$ and $1/\sqrt{2}.$

Edit

Yes, we can still find counterexamples. As the other person posted, we can find infinitely many helices with different torsion, but with the same normal vector $$N(s)=(-\cos{s},-\sin{s},0).$$

The difference between torsions comes from $a^2+b^2=1$. If I remember well, the torsion is given by $\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}$. I may be wrong about the formula, but as we can find infinitely many $a$ and $b$, we can also find infinitely many torsion values.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you found this question, but I suggest you look for counterexamples.

For example: Start with the unit circle as one curve. Then, parametrizing it by arclength, we'll have $\alpha(s)=(\cos s,\sin s,0)$, say, and $N(s)=(-\cos s,\sin s,0)$. Now, let's take any $a,b>0$ with $a^2+b^2=1$ and consider the circular helix $\beta(s)=(a\cos s,a\sin s, bs)$. The reader can now verify that $\beta$ is likewise arclength parametrized and that $N_\beta(s)=(-\cos s,-\sin s,0)$, as well.

Comment: I found it in a few places, unfortunately none of them is in English,

Comment: There must be extra hypotheses, then,  as I certainly have counterexamples.

Comment: only that $N$ is smooth

Comment: Why not just post a counterexample?

Comment: Well, @DanielSank, once one starts with a unit circle, if one's done any examples at all in differential geometry, other curves with the same principal normal field should be pretty clear. But if you can't think of any, I'll mumble *helix* quietly.

Comment: Yes yes but why not just say that in the answer and call it a day? Perhaps I'm not yet familiar enough with the style here, but on Physics.SE we like to just state the answer and get on with our lives :D

Comment: @DanielSank: Some of us still try to remain socratic here, but I admit that in this case it's not worth the trouble. Thanks. I'll edit.

Comment: Oh, yeah, Physics.SE tries to be Socratic with "solve this particular problem" type posts, but since the answer here is "your assumptions are wrong" it seemed appropriate to just come out and say it.